# How to group_by 4 or more variables using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to group my dataset for 4 variables. Variables a,b,c, and d.

Data frame example
[image]

Desired result
[image]

I wish to run the `group_by` function or group the 4 columns like this-

```
mydata %>%
group_by(col1, col2,col3,col4) %>%
summarise()
```

but it doesn't work, it only takes the first 3 columns. I see that the `group_by` call randomly chooses the column from the provided columns.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 2):

My *guess*, since you share no code: because you said *"it only takes first 3 columns"*, that suggests that with four arguments, the first is being interpreted as the dataframe. From that: `group_by(col1, col2, col3, col4)` with nothing before it is assuming that `col1` is data. If you had

```r
mydata # with or without this
group_by(col1, col2, col3, col4) %>%
  ...
```

then change it to

```r
mydata %>%
  group_by(col1, col2, col3, col4) %>%
  ...
```

or

```r
group_by(mydata, col1, col2, col3, col4) %>%
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only `group_by` does not make any visual change in the dataframe. You need to do something more after `group_by`.

Here is an example with `mtcars` dataset -

```
df <- mtcars[1:10, c(1, 2, 8, 9)]
df

#                   mpg cyl vs am
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  0  1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  0  1
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  1  1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  1  0
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  0  0
#Valiant           18.1   6  1  0
#Duster 360        14.3   8  0  0
#Merc 240D         24.4   4  1  0
#Merc 230          22.8   4  1  0
#Merc 280          19.2   6  1  0
```

Using only `group_by` -

```
df %>% group_by(cyl, vs, am)

# A tibble: 10 × 4
# Groups:   cyl, vs, am [5]
#     mpg   cyl    vs    am
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6     0     1
# 2  21       6     0     1
# 3  22.8     4     1     1
# 4  21.4     6     1     0
# 5  18.7     8     0     0
# 6  18.1     6     1     0
# 7  14.3     8     0     0
# 8  24.4     4     1     0
# 9  22.8     4     1     0
#10  19.2     6     1     0
```

You need to "tell" what you want to do after `group_by`, for example you can `sum` the `mpg` values.

```
df %>% group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>% summarise(sum_mpg = sum(mpg), .groups = 'drop')

#    cyl    vs    am sum_mpg
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4     1     0    47.2
#2     4     1     1    22.8
#3     6     0     1    42  
#4     6     1     0    58.7
#5     8     0     0    33
```

Comment: can you add another column named - pm with the randomized value and then try doing df %>% group_by(cyl, vs, am, pm) %>% summarise(sum_mpg = sum(mpg), .groups = 'drop')  ? This should help then. Thanks in advance.